# FreeBSD's pkg "No trusted fingerprint found matching package's certificate"

Tags: freebsd

I just installed FreeBSD 10 and trying to get `pkg` going, but something isn't working:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD  10.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 r260789: Thu Jan 16 22:34:59 UTC 2014     root@snap.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
# pkg
The package management tool is not yet installed on your system.
Do you want to fetch and install it now? [y/N]: Y
Bootstrapping pkg from pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest, please wait...
No trusted fingerprint found matching package's certificate
#
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the ports tree installed, just `make install clean` from `/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg`.

If you don't have ports:

```
fetch "http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest/Latest/pkg.txz"
setenv SIGNATURE_TYPE NONE
pkg add pkg.txz
```

If you're not using the default shell you might have to use `set` or `export` instead of `setenv`.

<sub>And now to rant about FreeBSD's ***idiotic*** decision to push a half baked, buggy piece of crapware to users when they *just* resolved critical issues found during their first release. I've never had so many issues with all the rest of FreeBSD (user since 4.x) as I have with the new `pkg` software. I can't even explain how disappointed I am with the lack of rigorous testing, particularly error handling and messages; lack of documentation (man pages are out of date, the handbook is terribly outdated); lack of a functional package system in the base install (only a bootstrap script is included in base, not the actual software). Seriously guys, WTF were you thinking?!</sub>

Comment: I was able to install, I believe the reason it didn't installed "normal" way is due to websense blocked it).